# ffplay attempt to subscribe to rtmp server failing with: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I have an nginx rtmp server loaded with this docker image: https://github.com/DvdGiessen/nginx-rtmp-docker.

In general I can stream to it fine with ffmpeg and most of the time connect to the stream fine as well with ffplay. However, for some people, they are unable to subscribe to the RTMP stream at all.

ffmpeg hosts with this command:

`ffmpeg.exe -f,gdigrab,-framerate,20,-draw_mouse,1,-i,desktop,-c:v,h264_nvenc,-profile:v,main,-delay,0,-preset,default,-rc,vbr,-cq,36,-vf,scale=1024:-2,format=yuv420p,-r,20,-g,40,-y,-f,flv,rtmp://url`

ffplay subscribes with this command:

`ffplay.exe -fflags,nobuffer,-flags,low_delay,-an,-window_title,Screen of User,-framedrop,rtmp://url`

The URL does match the url to which the host is streaming from. What happens is that for about 30 seconds, nothing happens with the following ffplay output:

`nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

 nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

 nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

which repeats until after a while I get the following error:

`RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header`

`2018/mm/dd 12:--:--:-- [web] rtmp://url: Invalid data found when processing input`

I tried doing what this recommended in regards to the NGINX server setup here: https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/1039, setting my worker_processes to 1 which did not change anything.

It seems like it may just be ffplay timing out but I cannot tell why it occurs only for a few users and not widely. If it is ffplay timing out, what can be done to fix the problem? It doesn't seem like an internet speed issue, as these subscribers have pretty good internet. I cannot replicate across different machines, only those few who have continued to have this problem. Any and all help would be appreciated!